# i want to retrieve records for containedgroupid corresponding to groupid

Tags: mysql

Here i show one table i want to retrieve containedgroupid corresponding to groupid

This is my query

```
select groupname,containedgroupid 
from groups g1 
where (select 
containedgroupid 
from groups g2 
where g1.containedgroupid=g2.containedgroupid);

+---------+----------------+------------------+
| groupid | groupname      | containedgroupid |
+---------+----------------+------------------+
|       0 | ANDHRA PRADESH |                0 |
|       1 | KERALA         |                5 |
|       2 | TAMILNADU      |                4 |
|       3 | MADHYAPRADESH  |                3 |
|       4 | PUNJAB         |                3 |
|       5 | CHENNAI        |                2 |
|       6 | KARNATAKA      |                2 |
|       7 | MAHARASTRA     |                1 |
|       8 | HARYANA        |                5 |
+---------+----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: select groupname,containedgroupid from groups g1 where (select containedgroupid from groups g2 where g1.containedgroupid=g2.containedgroupid);